# Add some dry run option to script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a script that accepts an argument and if not set uses a default.

```
VALUE=$1
if [[ -z "$VALUE" ]];  
   VALUE=foo #some function returns the default  
fi
```

Then the script goes on doing somethings.
I would like to "enhance" it and provide some `dry run` option. So that if
that is passed we would have something like

```
if [[ -z "$DRY" ]];  
  echo "command x y z"  
else 
  command "x" "y" "z"  
fi
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you show us some actual code trying to achieve here? What is wrong with the code you have showed

Comment: @Inian: I am not sure how to pass the dry run option in a nice way since the first argument is optional

Comment: Is the dry run option one argument or multiple arguments? You could just parameter expansion to identify a missing string right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do proper command line parsing and then choose how to do the actual dry running.

The command line parsing:

```
#!/bin/sh

dry_run=false

while getopts 'n' opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        n) dry_run=true ;;
        *) echo 'error in command line parsing' >&2
           exit 1
    esac
done
```

Now, `$dry_run` will be `true` if the user invoked the script with the `-n` command line option.

Then, choose how to do the dry running.  A simple way would be to use `set -v` (display the commands as they are read by the shell) followed by `set -n` (don't actually run *anything*):

```
if "$dry_run"; then
    set -v
    set -n
fi
```

This may not be what you want though as it would just display the script.

Instead you may choose to do

```
if "$dry_run"; then
    cmd=echo
else
    cmd=''
fi
```

and then prefix the specific commands that you'd like to dry run with `$cmd`:

```
$cmd ls -l
$cmd echo "hello world"
```

Comment: The trick with `$cmd ls` is just awsome!

Comment: @Jim Just note that you will have to insert it before every separate command.  `$cmd cat file | awk` will not work (`awk` will still run). Likewise `$cmd somecommand >file` will echo the command to the file.

Comment: That is extremely important, @Kusalananda! For piped commands, what I did is to define the `$pipe_cmd` as `'cat && echo '`, otherwise simply repeating `echo` will swallow the preceding command: `echo hello | echo dude` will print just `dude`, while `echo hello | cat && echo dude` will print both strings.

Comment: To complete: to avoid newlines between piped commands, either use `echo -n` or define `cmd_pipe` as `tr '\n' ' ' | cat && echo '`.